# Selecting a range using variable

Tags: vba

The following code gives me an "Application defined or object defined error"

```
Sub Apply_Changes()
    Dim col_ref As Integer
    col_ref = 5
    Worksheets("Sheet1").range(Cells(10, col_ref),cells(20,col_ref)).Select
End Sub
```

Could someone explain?

Is there another way of defining the range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must qualify your `Cells()` otherwise you are saying "The cells in whatever worksheet is currently active", which doesn't make sense inside of `Worksheeets("Sheet1").Range()`

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, col_ref),Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(20,col_ref)).Select
```

Consider, instead doing this like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, col_ref).Resize(10).Select
```

Essentially resizing the single cell 10 more rows (down to 20).

Comment: Perhaps Sheet1 isn't currently active?  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`. I question your need to actually "Select" this range though. Why just select a range at all? That's something a human does, your VBA probably doesn't need to.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the parantage to the Cells() inside the Range.:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, col_ref),Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(20,col_ref)).Select
```

or use with to shorten:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .range(.Cells(10, col_ref),.cells(20,col_ref)).Select
End with
```

---

Note I assume this is for practice, the selecting of a range to do something to it is wasted energy, simply do what you want to the range.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .range(.Cells(10, col_ref),.cells(20,col_ref)).copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End with
```

If you want to actually select the range then the sheet must be active:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Activate
    .range(.Cells(10, col_ref),.cells(20,col_ref)).Select
End with
```

Comment: Now it's telling me "Select method of range class failed"